# Using v-else-if and events VueJS

Tags: html, vue.js

I'm new at VueJS, and I getting a little trouble to understand how to use events with `v-else-if`. What I'm trying to do is when the user input a number, a text will be shown to him! This is what I got so far:

HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.22/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p v-if="number === '1'">You can see me!</p>
  <p v-else-if="number === '2'">Do you also see me?</p>
  <p v-else>Hello</p>
  <input v-on:input="changeText" />
</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

VueJS:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        number: '1',
    },
    methods: {
        changeText = function(event){
            this.number = event.target.value;
        }
    }
})
```

Can somebody help? Thanks so much you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax of defining the methods is off; You either do:

```
changeText (event){
  ...
}
```

Or:

```
changeText: function(event){
  ...
}
```

Comment: Also, instead of using `<input v-on:input="changeText">` OP can use `<input v-model="number" />`.

Comment: Thanks man, it is working now, I'm always forgetting that is : instead of = to defining in VueJS. It was a serious lack of attention, thanks so much!!

Comment: @Terry, It works fine too, It's good pratice to use v-on or v-mode? Really thanks btw.

Comment: @ArthurOliveira I personally prefer using `v-model`, because you don't need to define and maintain an additional method. Imagine if you have a rather large form wtih 20 input elements, you wouldn't want to define 20 methods whose only purpose is to update the data of the component :) remember D-R-Y.

Comment: @ArthurOliveira Also if you use `v-model` you get two way reactivity. Meaning that if you change `this.number` to any other value within your component, the input element value will reflect that. If you you're just reacting to the `@input` event then you're not syncing the value back to the input element.

Comment: @Terry understood, really makes more sence to use v-model. Thanks so much man!

Comment: @Bogdan Thanks so much man, that's true man, didn't think about that. To submit a form, for example, I wouldn't be passing the value of the input, if I use `@input`, right?

Comment: @ArthurOliveira If the form gets submitted the by the browser (not by you with an AJAX request) then you're fine, because the value is stored within the input DOM element and is independent from your vue specific code.

Comment: @ArthurOliveira The use of `v-model` just helps your value to be synced between your the Vue component and the actual `<input>` element value. These following two snippes do the same thing. So this `<input :value="number" @input="changeText">` is the same as this `<input v-model="number">`. That's why @Terry pointed out the it's better to use `v-model` because it takes care of the `@input` event logic for you, so you don't need to define a method for each input.

Comment: @Bogdan Understood man, I can see now that is better to use v-model, it does the two things by himself. Thanks so much, you guys really helped!

Answer (score 1):

I'm leaving this comment for perpetuity, as Psidom's comment perfectly fixes your problem. The original issue is due to incorrect syntax, using `changeText: function(event){ ... }` will fix the problem. If you open your browser's devtool console, you will immediately see a syntax error being logged.

However, this issue can be completely avoided if the method is not declared at the first place. Since you are actually simply trying to use an `<input>` element to directly modify the component's `data`, you can do it via using `v-model`. This can dramatically reduce redundancy in your code, especially when you have multiple input elements.

In your case, using `<input v-model="number">` will work perfectly fine:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        number: '1'
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.22/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <p v-if="number === '1'">You can see me!</p>
    <p v-else-if="number === '2'">Do you also see me?</p>
    <p v-else>Hello</p>
    <input v-model="number">
</div>
```